# Compare last modification dates of local and remove files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can get a last modification date of the remote file using

```
curl --head http://url 2>/dev/null | grep -Po '(?<=^Last-Modified:\s).*$'
```

This gets me date/time such as

```
Wed, 04 Sep 2013 19:53:18 GMT
```

---

For local file I can use

```
find /path/file -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \;
```

and it gets me date/time such as

```
2012-01-09 09:50:30.000000000 -0500
```

---

How can I compare this dat/time with last modification date of the local file? Please note that time zone may be different for remote and local file.

Comment: You can get the first date and do `date -d"Wed, 04..." "+%y"`

Comment: Depending on the version of `stat` you're using, you can just ask it to show you the ctime in a different format. eg: `stat -c '%Y'` for Gnu stat, or `stat -f '%c'` for BSD stat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `date -d` to parse the string, as @fedorqui says. Try running the below commands:

```
$ date -d "$(<your curl command grepped>)" +%s   #+%s gets you timestamp.
$ date -d "$(<your find command>)" +%s
```

To actually compare, you can subtract the timestamps, something like:

```
$ echo $(( $(date -d "$(<curl cmd>)" +%s)  -   $(date -d "$(<find cmd>)" +%s) ))
```

Comment: I like this a lot, I am using this curl command to get a remote file's modified date:  https://superuser.com/questions/619592/get-modification-time-of-remote-file-over-http-in-bash-script/619594#619594

In addition: if you use the stat command mentioned above, the echo comparison is NOT zero (0) if the local file is non-existing.

`rcompare="$(( $(date -d "$rcurl" +%s)  -   $(date -d "$rfind" +%s) ))"
if [[ $rcompare -eq 0 ]]
  then
   echo "Local file already up to date"
  else
   echo "Updating or overwrite local file"
   wget -q $remote_url -O $localfilename
  fi`